# How user can select a (existing) folder (not a file inside)

Tags: android, file, android-intent

i know how to create a Intent to pick a file:

```
public static Intent createGetContentIntent() {
    // Implicitly allow the user to select a particular kind of data
    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    // The MIME data type filter
    intent.setType("*/*");
    // Only return URIs that can be opened with ContentResolver
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    return intent;
}
```

But currently i want that the user simply browse to a directory and then read the selected directory in my app. Is it possible? Thanks!!

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to select a directory, not a file? For that you could use https://github.com/passy/Android-DirectoryChooser. You could also look to see how he did it if you want a more custom implementation.

Comment: @JoeyDalu thx but i'd like to do it in a native way, with no external libraries

Answer (score 0):

Add [a directory picker library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/35) to your app, and allow the user to pick a directory that way.

Or, if your `minSdkVersion` is 21+, you could use [`ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE) (part of [the Storage Access Framework](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/05/03/storage-access-framework-faq.html)), so long as you realize that the user is not picking a directory but rather a content tree, and you will use `DocumentFile` to work with the resulting `Uri`.

Comment: thx but i'd like to do it in a native way, with no external libraries

Comment: @Billyjoker: There is no "native way" prior to Android 5.0 (API Level 21) and `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`.